# discord.js Sharding Ready Timeout V12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I get this error when starting up my bot, does anyone have a reason why?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const { ShardingManager } = require('discord.js')
const manager = new ShardingManager('./bot.js', {
    totalShards: 'auto',
    token: 'token'
});
manager.on('shardCreate', shard => {
    console.log(`Launched shard ${shard.id}`)
    shard.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Shard ready')
    })
    shard.on('disconnect', (a, b) => {
        console.log('Shard disconnected')
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    })
    shard.on('reconnecting', (a, b) => {
        console.log('Shard reconnecting')
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    })
    shard.on('death', (a, b) => {
        console.log('Shard died')
        client.destroy()
        client.login("token")
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b)
    })
})

setTimeout(() => {
    manager.spawn()
},30000)
```

I looked online and I couldn't find a answer that was for my version, V12. Thanks in advance!
This is the error that I get:

```
0|index    |     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:329:20)
0|index    |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:277:12)
0|index    | Error [SHARDING_READY_TIMEOUT]: Shard 1's Client took too long to become ready.
0|index    |     at Timeout.onTimeout (/home/connor/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/sharding/Shard.js:163:16)
0|index    |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
0|index    |     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7) {
0|index    |   [Symbol(code)]: 'SHARDING_READY_TIMEOUT'
0|index    | }
```

Comment: What error, can you paste whole stack trace?

Comment: 0|index    |     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:329:20)
0|index    |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:277:12)
0|index    | Error [SHARDING_READY_TIMEOUT]: Shard 1's Client took too long to become ready.
0|index    |     at Timeout.onTimeout (/home/connor/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/sharding/Shard.js:163:16)
0|index    |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
0|index    |     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7) {
0|index    |   [Symbol(code)]: 'SHARDING_READY_TIMEOUT'
0|index    | }